# Puppet enterprise versus free version, what's the diff?

Tags: puppet

What are the differences between the free puppet version and the enterprise version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [their website](http://info.puppetlabs.com/puppet-enterprise):

> Puppet Enterprise packages the power of Puppet for ease of installation, maintenance and scalability
>
> - Simplified integration & installation
> - Tuned for scalaibility
> - All components tested and approved by Puppet Labs engineers
> - Built-in support as part of your paid license
> - Your Puppet deployment is always up to date

Comment: And the fact that enterprise version only allows you to run up to 10 nodes.

Answer (score 3):

Puppetlabs provides a break down of the differences here: http://puppetlabs.com/puppet/enterprise-vs-open-source

The most noticeable difference is support, a much improved web UI and as of 3.x better ability to view what happened during a puppet run.

Additional information

http://puppetlabs.com/puppet/faq